# Full screen size is too small for Nexus 5 in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement an application in flutter, and I want this app to be full screen.

Dispite my effort, I can't figure out how to have the screen size correctly.

Here is my code:

```dart
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final vm = Provider.of<LoginViewModel>(context);
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(BACKGROUND_COLOR),
        body: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 1,
            heightFactor: 1,
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: <Widget>[
                      Container(child: LoginForm(loginViewModel: vm)),
                      Container(child: CreateAccountSuggestor()),
                      Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
                          child: SocialConnectors()),
                    ])))));
  }
}
```

But I end up having a bar on the bottom:

[image: App screenshot]

This bar is the heigh of the nexus 5 bottom bar.

How can I obtain the full size heigh of the screen dynamically sor the blue container would be full screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your Scaffold :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  return Container(color: Colors.blue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I'll study more deeply how to make a reactive UI in flutter, I'm not enough at my ease with it!

Answer (score 0):

wrap your Scaffold with SafeArea and set the property of bottom and top to false.

Comment: I did but it didn't helped :/